# .net 4.6 on windows 7 - failed to run

Tags: windows-7-x64, .net-4.6

I've built an application in VS2015 with intention to run on .NET 4.6 only. So I went to the app.config file and edited it to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.6" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Then on my target machine (win 7, 64bit) I have installed the .NET 4.6 (Web installation). Even after rebooting that machine and trying to run my application I get the error saying that my application requires one of the following versions of .NET Framework - v4.6. Why is that? It seems like the 4.6 is not recognized by Windows 7? Thanks in advance.
E

Comment: Don't edit the config file yourself, VS generates one when you target 4.6.  It is good at avoiding typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supportedRuntime version (first version Id) is invalid. It should be "4.0" instead of "4.6".

```
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
</startup>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have already figured this out since August but I appreciate your help.